# OS files into ISO file (MikeOS)

Tags: operating-system

I downloaded MikeOS and I ran his OS through Oracle VirtualBox and I thought it would be fun to tweak the OS a bit by adding programs/features etc.

So I modified some code, and I know the code is right because there were no compiling errors.

Anyway once the OS was modified, I downloaded MagicISO so I can make my own version of an ISO file to put the modified OS on.

However each time I try to boot up my ISO VirtualBox says "No Bootable Medium found!".

Am I turning it into an ISO wrong? Here is how MikeOS is formatted:

http://prntscr.com/37vchg

What I did was, I modified the "programs" folder with my new code then I copied everything in the folder shown in the screenshot above.

I pasted it into a new folder on the desktop called "MikeOS(modified)". I then right clicked and turned that folder into an ISO. Did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

PS: I can't add pictures because I need 20 Reputation.

Comment: Since it sounds like you're building on Windows (due to using MagicISO), the build instructions here: http://mikeos.berlios.de/handbook-sysdev.html#buildwindows tell how to get a bootable floppy image that you can boot from. I'm not sure how you use MagicISO to build a bootable CD image. If you're using Linux to build MikeOS, the Linux build instructions: http://mikeos.berlios.de/handbook-sysdev.html#buildlinux explain how `mkisofs` is used to build a bootable CD image.

Answer (score 0):

> "So I modified some code, and I know the code is right because there were no compiling errors."

Not sure what you mean by your code being "right".
"No compiling errors" just means your syntax was correct and all libraries, etc, were available. It doesn't mean your code is logically correct.

> "However each time I try to boot up my ISO VirtualBox says "No Bootable Medium found! Am I turning it into an ISO wrong?"

Yes, you're doing it wrong.

Any bootable disk, be it floppy, hard drive or CD, requires a boot block to be present on the bootable media. The boot block is hidden from normal user inspection.

When you rip a CD (or whatever) all you're doing is grabbing data files off the media which may include jpgs, exes, dlls, sys files, and/or whatever else you might have, but doesn't touch the boot block.

In your case, you had all your data files, some of which you modified, and then burned them to a CD. It may LOOK just like the CD you ripped, but YOUR CD doesn't have the boot block, so it won't boot - as you have now discovered.

To fix your problem you need to get a boot block image (or as magic ISO calls them, a "boot image file") and add it to your CD composition and THEN burn your CD. Then your CD will be "bootable".

There's a few ways of doing that, and I won't go into that, but look under the "tools" tab of magiciso to get you started.